# Animating column chart from google charts

Tags: javascript, titanium, google-visualization, appcelerator

I'm having trouble coming up with a function that will animate a single column bar inside of my chart when I use a slider going back and forth..left and right.. I have read the animation docs on the Google Charts API documentation, but I am having a hard time understanding what I need to do.

Here is my code so far. Where would I start in figuring out how to animate just one of my bars using a slider I have made in titanium? I call the function `updateChart()` from my app.js file using the evalJS function. I have verified it works, by doing a console.log when my slider goes back and forth. I just can't seem to wrap my head around it how to apply this to animating a single column bar. Any thoughts are appreciated.

Set up Google Charts on my html page.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src ="https://www.google.com/jsapi" > </script>
    <script type="text/javascript ">
        google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Importance');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Earning');
            data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'style'});

            data.addRows([['',5,'#000000'], ['',5,'#ffffff'],['',5,'#666666'],['', 5,'#cccccc']]); 

        var options = 
        {
            width: 200, 
            height: 240, 
            legend: {
                position: 'none'
            }, 
            chartArea: {
                backgroundColor: 'none'
            }, 
            bar: {
                groupWidth: '100%'
            },
            animation: {
                duration: 1000,
                easing: 'out'
            }
        };

        function updateChart() {

        }

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
```

EDITED CODE:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src ="https://www.google.com/jsapi" > </script>
    <script type="text/javascript ">
        google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Importance');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Earning');
            data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'style'});

            data.addRows([['',5,'#000000'], ['',5,'#ffffff'],['',5,'#666666'],['', 5,'#cccccc']]); 

                var options = {
                width: 200, 
                height: 240, 
                legend: {
                    position: 'none'
                }, 
                chartArea: {
                    backgroundColor: 'none'
                }, 
                bar: {
                    groupWidth: '100%'
                },
                animation: {
                    duration: 1000,
                    easing: 'out'
                }
        };

        function updateChart(value) {
            data.setValue(0, 1, value);
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
```

Slider Hook Code in separate file (app.js) Titanium Platform

```
var sliderBarOne = Titanium.UI.createSlider({
    top: '310',
    left: '610',
    min: '0',
    max: '10',
    width: '37%',
    value: '5',
    backgroundImage: 'assets/sliderBar.png'
});
sliderBarOne.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    chartView.evalJS("updateChart('" + e.value + "');");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to hook up an event listener for your slider that calls the `updateChart` function.  The `updateChart` function should get the value from the slider and change the value in the DataTable, then cal the chart's `draw` method.  How you hook up an event listener to the slider is going to depend on the library you are using for the slider.  Here's some example code that assumes your slider object has a `change` method to set a change event handler and a `getValue method to get the value of the slider:

**[edit: added in your slider code]**

```
function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Importance');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Earning');
    data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'style'});

    data.addRows([
        ['',5,'#000000'],
        ['',5,'#ffffff'],
        ['',5,'#666666'],
        ['', 5,'#cccccc']
    ]); 

    var options = {
        width: 200, 
        height: 240, 
        legend: {
            position: 'none'
        }, 
        chartArea: {
            backgroundColor: 'none'
        }, 
        bar: {
            groupWidth: '100%'
        },
        animation: {
            duration: 1000,
            easing: 'out'
        }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    function updateChart(value) {
        data.setValue(0, 1, value);
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }

    // create slider
    var sliderBarOne = Titanium.UI.createSlider({
        top: '310',
        left: '610',
        min: '0',
        max: '10',
        width: '37%',
        value: '5',
        backgroundImage: 'assets/sliderBar.png'
    });

    sliderBarOne.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        updateChart(e.value);
    });

    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Comment: I got the value finally passed to the function and I can see it's value changing in the console.log with the slider, but the chart is still not changing. Thoughts?

Comment: I see the updated code, but I don't see how you are hooking into the slider's change event.

Comment: I added the hook..check it out.

Comment: OK.  The problem there is an issue of scope.  The `updateChart` function only exists inside the scope of drawchart, so you have to move your slider code there, like in my example.  You shouldn't need to use evalJS for this.

Comment: I made the slider from titanium, hmm..let me try your code. I also added the titanium slider code up there.

Comment: I edited my code to include your slider code, if that helps clarify.

Comment: I got my chart animating finally, but it's giving me this error.

Uncaught Error: Type mismatch. Value 5.062717770034843 does not match type string in column index 2

Comment: If your DataTable resembles the one above, then column 2 is the colors column, which cannot take a number as a value.